# Using Bootstrap 5 for responsive label name next to input field

Tags: bootstrap-5

I try to make label and input field responsive next to each other in Bootstrap 5. Here is my code:

```
 <main class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-md-3 py-4">
           
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8">

        <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
            <button class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-home" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</button>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
            <button class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-profile" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</button>
          </li>
          
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
          <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab" tabindex="0">

            <div class="row">

              <div class="col-md-6">
               
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                     
                        <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Price:</label>
                       
                        <input type="number" class="form-control col-sm-10" >
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <span class="input-group-text">USD</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3 ">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Amount:</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control col-sm-10" >
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <span class="input-group-text">BTC</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3 ">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Total:</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control col-sm-10">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <span class="input-group-text">USD</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                 
                </div>
           
             </div>


          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab" tabindex="0">...</div>
          
        </div>
        

      </div>

    </div>
 
 
  </main>
```

The problem is when screen size change to small screen, label is not responsive. It does not move over input field. Why does this happen?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have the labels taking up a col-3 and the inputs taking up a col-10. Bootstrap only goes up to col-12. Reduce the label size or reduce the input size.

```html
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Amount:</label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control col-sm-10" />
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <span class="input-group-text">BTC</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/columns/

Comment: plz copy my code and test it. col-sm-2 is not solve the problem

Comment: @john: please note that Stack Overflow is not a platform where free labour can be demanded. Consider taking this answer and doing further research yourself, adding comments to RShannon here when you have done so. This will help you practice becoming more independent as an engineer.